# Pandas pivot\transpose rows to column headings

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to learn pandas and wondering how the below can be achieved...

[image: example of input and output]

Dataframe to start with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Person1', 'Person1'],
    'SetCode1': ['L6A', 'L6A'],
    'SetDetail1': ['B', 'C'],
    'SetCode2': ['G2G', 'G2G'],
    'SetDetail2': ['B', 'B'],
})
```

Comment: i've added an example of your dataframe to start with, so maybe others can help you. I don't know the answer to this question, but I'm sure someone else will. It is best practice to add a sample data in code (not a photo!) to make it easy for others to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `pd.wide_to_long` and `unstack`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Person1', 'Person1'],
    'SetCode1': ['L6A', 'L6A'],
    'SetDetail1': ['B', 'C'],
    'SetCode2': ['G2G', 'G2G'],
    'SetDetail2': ['B', 'B'],
})


df_melt = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                          ['SetCode', 'SetDetail'], 
                          ['index', 'Name'], 
                          'No')

df_out = df_melt.set_index('SetCode', append=True)\
                .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)['SetDetail']\
                .unstack()
df_out
```

Output:

```
SetCode       G2G L6A
index Name           
0     Person1   B   B
1     Person1   B   C
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a column renaming than pivoting I think. here is my code

```
code_cols = list(filter(lambda s: s.startswith('SetCode'), df.columns))
det_cols = list(filter(lambda s: s.startswith('SetDetail'), df.columns))
codes = [df[s][0] for s in code_cols]
df.rename(columns = dict(zip(det_cols, codes)), inplace=True)
df.drop(columns = code_cols, inplace=True)
df
```

produces

```
    Name    L6A G2G
0   Person1 B   B
1   Person1 C   B
```

Thanks to @Sander van den Oord for typing in the dataframe!

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas.wide_to_long` is the right solution, although one must be cautious with the `NaN` values that you have in certain columns.

Therefore, here follows an adaptation of Scott Boston's answer:

```
import pandas as pd

# I just allowed myself to write 'Person2' instead of 'Person1' at the second row
# of the DataFrame, as I imagine this is what was originally intended in the data,
# but this does not change the method
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Person1', 'Person2'],
    'SetCode1': ['L6A', 'L6A'],
    'SetDetail1': ['B', 'C'],
    'SetCode6': ['U2H', None],
    'SetDetail6': ['B', None],
})
print(df)

      Name SetCode1 SetDetail1 SetCode6 SetDetail6
0  Person1      L6A          B      U2H          B
1  Person2      L6A          C     None       None

# You will need to use reset_index to keep the original index moving forward only if
# the 'Name' column does not have unique values
df_melt = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['SetCode', 'SetDetail'], ['Name'], 'No')

df_out = df_melt[df_melt['SetCode'].notnull()]\
    .set_index('SetCode', append=True)\
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)['SetDetail']\
    .unstack()
print(df_out)

SetCode L6A  U2H
Name            
Person1   B    B
Person2   C  NaN
```